How to make IDE type-checking recognize dynamically added methods from a class decorator in Python?
This is my code:
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class NewMethodsMixin:
    def new_method(self) -> str:
        """This is a new method added by a mixin."""
        print("added by mixin")


def class_decorator(cls: Type[T]):
    class Decorated(NewMethodsMixin, cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return Decorated


@class_decorator
class MyClass:
    def old_method(self) -> str:
        print("original method")


my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.old_method()  # 'original method'
my_instance.new_method()  # 'added by mixin'

This is how it looks in the IDE:
1
I wish to get type hints for old_method.
And if I use another approch:
...

def class_decorator(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
...

This is how it looks in the IDE:
2
Now I get the type hint for old_method, but lose the type hint for new_method.
If I use the Union:
...
def class_decorator(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T] | Type[NewMethodsMixin]:
...

This is how it looks in the IDE:
3
Apparently, pylance or other type hints can handle the decorated class correctly, but if I inherit the new class, this will cause a failure.
For some reasons I prefer to use decorators instead of using class inheritance as my users may not be able to handle the issue of multiple inheritance. Is there any solution here?

You need intersection types (pseudocode: (cls: type[T]) -> type[T] & type[NewMethodsMixin]), which are not a thing yet.

A few existing questions on the same topic: How to express multiple inheritance in Python type hint?, Workaround for lack of intersection types with Python generics?.
